# For same task, why more threads lead to less instructions

Tags: c++, instructions, stdthread

**Code**

I ran my program 30 times, and `n` passed to `run_and_join_threads()` changed from 1 to 30 accordingly.

Note that `jobs` passed to `run_and_join_threads()` were populated by exactly the same way in each execution.

```
void do_job(JobQueue *jobs) {
    Job job;
    while (job = jobs->pop())
        job();

    // control flow goes here if jobs.pop() returns nullptr,
    // which means all the jobs have been done
}

void run_and_join_threads(int n, JobQueue &jobs) {
    vector<thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        threads.push_back(thread(do_job, &jobs));

    // synchronization
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        threads[i].join();
}
```

JobQueue.h

```
#ifndef JOB_QUEUE_H
#define JOB_QUEUE_H

#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>

typedef std::function<void (void)> Job;

// Its methods are all atomic.
class JobQueue {
    std::queue<Job> jobs;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:
    void push(Job job);

    // pop removes the "oldest" job in the queue and returns it.
    // pop returns nullptr if there's no more jobs left in the queue.
    Job pop();
};

#endif
```

JobQueue.cc

```
#include "JobQueue.h"

using namespace std;

void JobQueue::push(Job job) {
    mtx.lock();
    jobs.push(job);
    mtx.unlock();
}

Job JobQueue::pop() {
    Job job = nullptr;
    mtx.lock();
    if (!jobs.empty()) {
        job = jobs.front();
        jobs.pop();
    }
    mtx.unlock();
    return job;
}
```

**Chart**

I use `perf stat -e instructions:u ./my_program` to record number of instructions during my program execution.

I then found that there is a negative correlation between number of threads and number of user instructions.
[image: threads_instructions]

**My Thoughts**

Since the "real task" remains the same, more threads should lead to more thread construction and destruction, which results in more instructions, but that's not the case from the chart. I tried to google with the keywords in the title, but no luck.

compilation options: `-std=c++14 -pthread -Wextra -Werror -MMD`
gcc version: `8.2.1 20180831`

**Output of `--per-thread` when n = 10**

```
     hw4-9525               8,524.37 msec task-clock:u              #    0.153 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9524               8,082.77 msec task-clock:u              #    0.145 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9522               7,824.93 msec task-clock:u              #    0.140 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9519               7,782.65 msec task-clock:u              #    0.139 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9518               7,734.42 msec task-clock:u              #    0.138 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9517               7,722.12 msec task-clock:u              #    0.138 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9520               7,636.99 msec task-clock:u              #    0.137 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9425              11,899.78 msec task-clock:u              #    0.213 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9521               7,585.14 msec task-clock:u              #    0.136 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9526               7,580.60 msec task-clock:u              #    0.136 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9523               7,306.57 msec task-clock:u              #    0.131 CPUs utilized
     hw4-9425                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9517                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9518                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9519                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9520                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9521                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9522                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9523                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9524                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9525                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9526                      0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9425                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9517                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9518                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9519                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9520                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9521                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9522                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9523                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9524                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9525                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9526                      0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
     hw4-9425                  9,332      page-faults:u             # 1144.724 M/sec
     hw4-9520                  7,487      page-faults:u             #  918.404 M/sec
     hw4-9526                  7,408      page-faults:u             #  908.714 M/sec
     hw4-9522                  7,401      page-faults:u             #  907.855 M/sec
     hw4-9518                  7,386      page-faults:u             #  906.015 M/sec
     hw4-9524                  7,362      page-faults:u             #  903.071 M/sec
     hw4-9521                  7,348      page-faults:u             #  901.354 M/sec
     hw4-9525                  7,258      page-faults:u             #  890.314 M/sec
     hw4-9517                  7,253      page-faults:u             #  889.700 M/sec
     hw4-9519                  7,153      page-faults:u             #  877.434 M/sec
     hw4-9523                  6,194      page-faults:u             #  759.797 M/sec
     hw4-9425         24,365,706,871      cycles:u                  # 2988857.145 GHz
     hw4-9524         19,199,338,912      cycles:u                  # 2355116.623 GHz
     hw4-9518         18,658,195,691      cycles:u                  # 2288736.452 GHz
     hw4-9522         18,565,304,421      cycles:u                  # 2277341.801 GHz
     hw4-9520         18,524,344,417      cycles:u                  # 2272317.378 GHz
     hw4-9519         18,452,590,959      cycles:u                  # 2263515.629 GHz
     hw4-9521         18,384,181,678      cycles:u                  # 2255124.099 GHz
     hw4-9517         18,169,025,051      cycles:u                  # 2228731.578 GHz
     hw4-9526         17,957,925,085      cycles:u                  # 2202836.674 GHz
     hw4-9523         17,689,877,988      cycles:u                  # 2169956.262 GHz
     hw4-9525         20,380,269,586      cycles:u                  # 2499977.312 GHz
     hw4-9524         35,930,781,858      instructions:u            #    1.88  insn per cycle
     hw4-9425         31,238,610,254      instructions:u            #    1.63  insn per cycle
     hw4-9522         34,856,962,399      instructions:u            #    1.82  insn per cycle
     hw4-9518         34,794,129,974      instructions:u            #    1.82  insn per cycle
     hw4-9520         34,565,759,122      instructions:u            #    1.81  insn per cycle
     hw4-9519         34,521,122,564      instructions:u            #    1.81  insn per cycle
     hw4-9521         34,389,796,009      instructions:u            #    1.80  insn per cycle
     hw4-9517         33,823,905,990      instructions:u            #    1.77  insn per cycle
     hw4-9525         38,084,271,354      instructions:u            #    1.99  insn per cycle
     hw4-9526         33,682,632,175      instructions:u            #    1.76  insn per cycle
     hw4-9523         33,147,549,812      instructions:u            #    1.73  insn per cycle
     hw4-9525          6,113,561,884      branches:u                # 749929530.566 M/sec
     hw4-9425          5,978,592,665      branches:u                # 733373322.423 M/sec
     hw4-9524          5,765,141,950      branches:u                # 707190060.107 M/sec
     hw4-9522          5,593,987,998      branches:u                # 686195195.687 M/sec
     hw4-9518          5,583,032,551      branches:u                # 684851328.824 M/sec
     hw4-9520          5,546,955,396      branches:u                # 680425868.769 M/sec
     hw4-9519          5,541,456,246      branches:u                # 679751307.023 M/sec
     hw4-9521          5,518,407,713      branches:u                # 676924023.050 M/sec
     hw4-9517          5,427,113,316      branches:u                # 665725254.544 M/sec
     hw4-9526          5,407,241,325      branches:u                # 663287626.012 M/sec
     hw4-9523          5,318,730,317      branches:u                # 652430286.226 M/sec
     hw4-9525             66,142,537      branch-misses:u           #    1.18% of all branches
     hw4-9524             61,835,669      branch-misses:u           #    1.10% of all branches
     hw4-9518             61,243,167      branch-misses:u           #    1.09% of all branches
     hw4-9520             60,266,206      branch-misses:u           #    1.07% of all branches
     hw4-9521             59,396,966      branch-misses:u           #    1.06% of all branches
     hw4-9522             59,227,658      branch-misses:u           #    1.05% of all branches
     hw4-9519             59,210,503      branch-misses:u           #    1.05% of all branches
     hw4-9526             57,983,090      branch-misses:u           #    1.03% of all branches
     hw4-9517             57,910,215      branch-misses:u           #    1.03% of all branches
     hw4-9523             56,251,632      branch-misses:u           #    1.00% of all branches
     hw4-9425             32,626,137      branch-misses:u           #    0.58% of all branches
```

Comment: Post a minimal, compilable program that embodies the question. right now we're just speculating.

Comment: Also,what's up with the convention? sometimes it's under scores, sometimes it's upper camel case..

Comment: What's the output with `--per-thread`?

Comment: What is JobQueue?

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm working on the minimal, compilable program, and I will make the naming consistent, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Damian I include it in my post now.

Comment: Side note: [Use RAII lock guards (lock_guard, unique_lock, shared_lock), never call mutex.lock and mutex.unlock directly (RAII)](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-unclassified)

Comment: @WernerHenze I've included it in my question.

Comment: Which of these values did you show in your graph? I fail to correlate the numbers.

Comment: @WernerHenze I use `perf stat -e instructions:u ./my_program` and show `insturctions:u` in my graph.

Comment: @DavidChen Thank you!

Comment: Your graph shows about 40 millions for 10 threads. `perf --per-thread` shows maximum 38 millions. That does not really match. But maybe `perf` only gave you the information for the main thread and not for all threads!? That's the reason why I asked for `--per-thread`.

Comment: @WernerHenze May that be caused by the latency between starting my program and issuing `perf stat --per-thread -p <pid>`?

Comment: Do you have the same result if you only stat only one event because, what is observed may be a consequence of sampling, which happens if your cpu does not have enough counters: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#multiplexing_and_scaling_events

Comment: @Oliv Thank you for the information, but I only `stat` one event, namely `instructions:u`, in my `perf` command.

Comment: @DavidChen Maybe you could perfom fine grained perf analisys with this libperf: https://github.com/theonewolf/libperf

Comment: @Oliv Thank you for the information, that seems interesting